# Proxy stops working on the production server by setting it in the elm-package.json

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, elm

> I'm using **create-elm-app** webpack for my ELM project.
>   And use a proxy by setting it in the `elm-package.json` and this is
>   working fine only on the dev server. When I created build by using
>   `elm-app build` then proxy stops working on the production server. Can
>   anyone please suggest me any solution to resolve this.

Here is my **elm-package.json**

```
{
"proxy": "https://some.domain.net/",
"version": "1.0.0",
"summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
"repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
"license": "BSD3",
"source-directories": [
    "src"
],
"exposed-modules": [],
"dependencies": {
    "NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline": "3.0.0 <= v < 4.0.0",
    "elm-community/list-extra": "7.1.0 <= v < 8.0.0",
    "elm-community/typed-svg": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
    "elm-lang/core": "5.0.0 <= v < 6.0.0",
    "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 4.0.1",
    "elm-lang/http": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0",
    "elm-lang/navigation": "2.1.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
    "evancz/url-parser": "2.0.1 <= v < 3.0.0",
    "krisajenkins/remotedata": "4.3.3 <= v < 5.0.0"
},
"elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. The proxy is only meant to aid in development so you can forward requests to a server elsewhere. This frees you from having to run an API server locally during front-end development. It mimics an environment where the Elm app and API server are served from the same host and port.

[More info on the Webpack `devServer` can be found here.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy)

When you build for production, the proxy concept is removed with the idea that you will be serving the Elm app and API back-end from the same host and port.